# dictionary from csv file python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have read a cvs file and I would like to create a dictionary from the information I have on that file. I´ve tried to use class  csv.DictReader to that propose but it didnt gave me the results i wanted.

Now i am reading the file like this:

```
size_reader = csv.reader(f,dialect='excel-tab')
```

and I have as result this:

```
['chr1', '249250621']
['chr2', '243199373']
['chr3', '198022430']
['chr4', '191154276']
['chr5', '180915260']
```

I would like to make a dictionary with this structure:

```
dict ['chr4'] = 191154276
dict ['chr5'] = 180915260
dict ['chr2'] = 243199373
```

I tried regular expressions to split the elements the lines on the file but I had no success with it, maybe i used the wrong characters in the split function. Could you give some suggestion of how to separate the elements and built the dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just convert it to a dict directly:

```
 result = dict(size_reader)
```

This takes each two-column result from your `size_reader` CVS reader and uses that as the key and value for a python dictionary.

To convert each value to integers, you'd need to use a dict comprehension to process each value:

```
result = {k: int(v) for k, v in size_reader}
```

Comment: @JonClements: Note to self: `{k: v for k, v in iterable}` == `dict(iterable)`.. Thanks.

Comment: @JonClements: Want to write an answer too? :-P

Comment: sure - but I don't think "See Martijn's answer" is a valid answer ;)